# Запись данных в таблицу Oracle

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

Здравствуйте. Записываю xml-файл в таблицу Oracle. Файлик записывается нормально, но мне нужно ещё записать нолик в поле типа намбер для того что бы потом проверять записали или нет xml файл дальше в нужную таблицу. Вот код запроса.

```
OracleCommand com = new OracleCommand("insert into Transfer_table (xmldoc, write_checks) VALUES (XMLType('" + xml + "','" + 0 + "'))", con);
```

На строчке

```
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Вылетает ошибка: not enough values. Не пойму что я делаю не так?

Comment: То, что ошибка и говорит - указали два поля для вставки, вставляете одно.

Comment: @0xdb всмысле одно? С помощью переменной xml вставляется xml-файл а во врайт чекс вставляется нолик. Почему же 1?

Comment: Ван уже ответили, будте внимательны со скобкамии.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если внимательно присмотреться к :

```
VALUES (XMLType('" + xml + "','" + 0 + "'))"
```

таки да, одно значение вставляете, должно быть так :

```
VALUES (XMLType('" + xml + "'),'" + 0 + "')"
```

Comment: Спасибо заработало.